# How to get JPanel to remember user-drawn graphics when panel is resized?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

I'm trying to make a program that allows users to place music notes on staffs. There is a class called SheetMusicPane that extends JPanel, and it starts out with a bunch of staffs drawn from top to bottom. By clicking on the buttons in the toolbar at the top, users can choose notes to draw. There is also a button on the toolbar that allows the user to increase the amount of sheet music available (the SheetMusicPane is set inside a JScrollPane). I don't know how to make the music notes copy over when the user resizes the SheetMusicPane. The initial staffs stay put, however.

I tried the JPanel.repaint() method; it didn't work.

The resizing is pretty simple:

```
JButton moreMusicButton = new JButton("Get More Sheet Music");
    tb.add(moreMusicButton);
    moreMusicButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           smp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scrollSize.width, smp.getHeight() +     moreMusicAmount));
           smp.repaint();
        }
    });
```

As said above, repaint() isn't doing anything.

Thanks in advance!

Adding note-drawing code:

The note-drawing buttons each call this method (the String "note" is obtained
from the button's ActionCommand):

```
  public void getShape(final Graphics g, final String note) {
     MouseListener[] listeners = this.getMouseListeners();
     for (MouseListener ml : listeners) {
        this.removeMouseListener(ml);  //makes graphics stop drawing previous note
     }
     this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
           addShape(g, p.x, p.y, note);
           int pitch = 12;
           piano.playNote(pitch);
           advance(1.0, piano);
           try { addToFile(pitch, note);}
           catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {}
           catch(IOException ioe) {}
        }
     });
  }
```

Here's how the panel itself is created. It comprises a set of private nested classes and it starts out showing plain, note-free sheet music.

private class SheetMusicPane extends JPanel {

```
  public SheetMusicPane() {
     final Graphics g = this.getGraphics();  
  } 

  //paints staffs
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     for (int i = 0; (i - 1)*staffWidth < scrollSize.height + 100; i++) {
        int y = paddingNorth + i*staffWidth;
        Staff staff = new Staff(g, y, "treble");
     }
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     for (String note : noteList) {
        addShape(g, 100, 200, note); 
     }
  }

  //takes in mouse info and calls addShape to draw notes on clicks
  public void getShape(final Graphics g, final String note) {  ... } //as shown above

  //draws a note
  private void addShape(Graphics g, int x, int y, String note) { ... }

  private void addToFile(int pitch, String note) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException { ...//adds note info to a file }
```

//just makes a five-line staff at this point
   private class Staff {

```
  private Graphics g;
  private int y;
  private int[] pitches;

  public Staff(Graphics g, int y, String cleff) {  ...//draws the lines }
```

}

Comment: How do you paint them?

Comment: With a mouse listener that is waiting on the SheetMusicPane. The user clicks on the panel and the note appears where the click occurred

Comment: just added note-drawing code

Comment: Wow, I think I've never seen a question this incoherent. Just put yourself in our place for a second: how do you think we can even imagine what is going wrong in your code with so little information? I mean, there are like a 1000 issues in your code and probably a million possible problems. Please shorten this to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that actually allows us to see the problem (I suspect it's actually "the many problems")

Comment: Do you want the size of the notes to resize with SheetMusicPane, or are they just not appearing?

Comment: The notes should stay the same size; only difference is that new space appears at the bottom (I have not yet tried to get the program to draw more staffs on the new space - that's for later)

Comment: Will try to come up with an SSCCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to override the paintComponent method of your Panel.
You save everything to paint in an Array (or List) and the paintComponent method draws them. (on every repaint).

If you draw them on click, the next time repaint() is called the Panel will be cleared and repainted using the paintComponent Method. Your drawings are as long on the Panel as reapaint() is not called.

Comment: OK now with the array idea here is what happens: The screen goes blank, the notes are drawn, and then if I scroll down the staffs appear and then I can't scroll up to see the notes anymore. Apparently the notes are drawn first, and then the panel is resized and repainted with staffs, even though I call setPreferredSize() on the panel first and then repaint the notes (which I did by overriding paintComponent and calling it in the resize method). I'll try to add more code to clarify things.

Comment: If you do the scrolling with a JScrollPane (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) you should have no problems

Comment: It works now. I was overriding both paint() and paintComponent() and it must have been doing paintComponent() first (for the notes) and then paint() (covering them up with blank staffs). Thanks for your help!